# After Git clone files belong to wrong user, cannot edit

Tags: git, github, clone, readonly

I am following a course online.
I have a repository to clone and work with the code in that repo but since yesterday whenever a clone a repo even the one i created my self it (local repository) is in READ-ONLY mode on my machine.
When I right-click on a `file -> property -> permission`, it is written that I am not the owner.

As a consequence, I cannot modify the code, so I can't go on in my course :(
I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Here are list of things I have done :

- restart the pc
- resetting git global `user.name` `user.email`
- I have tried to clone the repo in root mode (`sudo su`)
- deleting a working repo from my local machine when I tried to re-clone it from my GitHub: got the same issues.

I want this repo in particular : git clone https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects.git

I want to be able to modify the file like any other repo !

Comment: You mean you cannot push? Github has settings read write per project. Perhaps that changed?

Comment: i mean i can't modify any file localy (when i right- click on a file ->propert-> permission.it is written that i am not the owner ! therefore i can't modify permissions)i open the file in gedit for exemple i modifier things but then i cant save it as it is in ready-only mode . tempory solution : instead of cloning the repo i donwloaded it as a zip folder i created a local git  then i added the local repo to github

Comment: Are you using `sudo` when you `git clone`?

Comment: Explain how exactly you clone (give the path, the command, the log output). Git cannot create files read-only, but when you clone as root (using sudo), the files belong to root and can only be changed by root.

Comment: i basically go to a github repo i copy the link in this case :https://github.com/2chenj/info232  i open my terminal  in this case on my desktop i put sudo git clone https://github.com/2chenj/info232  i get the local repo with the padlock there is nothing suspects in terminal

Comment: @Chris actualy my error was to put a  `sudo` in front of my git command !

Answer (score 0):

I just tried cloning it, and this works without issue (correct owner/group)

```
vonc@vonvb:~/git$ git clone https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects.git
Cloning into 'ud120-projects'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5046, done.
remote: Total 5046 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 5046
Receiving objects: 100% (5046/5046), 19.64 MiB | 3.89 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4372/4372), done.
vonc@vonvb:~/git$ cd ud120-projects/
vonc@vonvb:~/git/ud120-projects$ l
total 84K
drwxr-xr-x  6 vonc vonc 4,0K juin  23 07:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 vonc vonc   86 juin  23 07:33 README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 vonc vonc  207 juin  23 07:33 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  2 vonc vonc 4,0K juin  23 07:33 feature_selection
```

Make sure you are not using an alias/script wrapper for the git command. (type `which git`). Check your `umask` (`0002`).

Comment: i am sure it works for others  i think i did bad manipulation  in my  ubuntu settings i was expecting that someone ever got the same issues and got solution !! with `which git` i get : **/usr/bin/git**  with  `umask`  i get : **0022**

Comment: @TOCHANGE so changing the umask was enough?

Comment: Not Really I Still Have The Same Issue  :( i guess i will have to re-install ubuntu ! it is giving me a hard time not to be able to git clone repo  though my terminal :(  note that i had this other java project and i was able to clone it though eclipse ofc this works only for projects whose programming language is supported by eclipse. this solution is not effecient in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify permissions from the terminal:

> root@root:sudo chmod 777 project_folder -R

`777` means Read Write Execute permissions for all the user